# What does it mean for the differential of one function to be "independent"?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose I have a set of smooth $k$  functions $F_{i}: M \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, where $i=1,...,k$ on a smooth manifold $M$. I encounter a theorem that states "Assume $dF_{i}$ are independent at each cotangent space $T_{x}M$".

What does this mean if I take $k=1$, i.e. I have only one $F$? How does then the independence condition look? Do I simply need that $dF$ is not identically vanishing, or something more?

Comment: Can you state the Theorem? I assume that dF not vanishing is enough to verify the theorem's condition

Comment: You need $dF$ to never vanish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean $F_i :M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so I will go with that assumption.

The derivative of each of these maps is $dF_i :TM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We define $$TM := \{(x, v(x)) : x \in M, ~ v(x) \in T_x M \}$$ and so if we restrict to $T_x M$ we are effectively looking at the maps $dF_i(x) : T_x M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. By how differentiation on a manifold works these maps will be linear so the question is asking you to assume that $dF_1(x), \ldots, dF_k(x)$ are linearly independent as linear maps.

Comment: For more info on this sort of thing from the ground up I'd recommend *Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications* by Marsden, Raitu and Abraham, pretty certain you can find pdf's of it on the internet.

Comment: Thanks. Just to check, here when we write $dF$ in this context, we mean the total derivative of $F$,  i.e. if we endow $M$ with coords $(x_{1}, ...,x_{n})$ we have $dF = (\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{1}},...\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{n}})$, right? So in case of just one $F$, we need that all components of the vector $dF$ don't vanish simultaneously when evaluated at $x$ ?  @S.Dewar

Comment: @Alex Pretty certain that is correct. I tend to think of it without coordinates tbh, so for any $x \in M$ and $\gamma'(0) \in T_xM$ (where $\gamma$ is a smooth curve with $\gamma(0)=x$) then $dF(x)( \gamma'(0)) = (f \circ \gamma)' (0)$.